# HQ Camera shows artifacts / raindrops

Tags: raspicam

A newly bought camera shows the following symptoms:

**Pictures without an objective / without a lens** show some unwanted artifacts:

[image: Picture without objective]

**Picture of the sensor surface / the green slice**:

[image: Sensor surface]

**Picture (with an objective)** of a barcode shows some fragments like raindrops at the lens (fuzziness of the thin line):

[image: Picture with objective]

**Other observations**: The sensor surface seems OK, but the green slice before the sensor surface seems to have roughness / scratches. It's nothing I can wipe away easily. And it seems that the roughness is at the outer side AND at the inner side of the green slice. The green slice does not seem to be a protective foil or something like that.

**Question**: Is there something I can do to correct this on my own? Or should I just send it back to the seller?

Comment: those look like scratches made in soft plastic film ... refer to the user manual ... speak to the seller before you do anything

Comment: OK. I spoke to the seller and he/she also thinks that it's broken, so it's on the way back.